# How do you dynamically add attributes(with value) to an element in VueJs

Tags: vue.js

I have an eement in Vue that looks like this

```
<button :data-popover-target="!doesAllEventTypesHaveEventAttached ? 'all-event-type-not-satisfied' : 'no-action_all-event-type-not-satisfied'" data-popover-placement="left" :disabled="!doesAllEventTypesHaveEventAttached" type="button"> Send </button>
```

I want to add `data-popover-target="all-event-type-not-satisfied"` only when `!doesAllEventTypesHaveEventAttached` is true. When !doesAllEventTypesHaveEventAttached is false, I want the whole attribute gone. This is because the value of the attribute is an element id and I would not want to create a dangling ID that does nothing(that is what 'no-action_all-event-type-not-satisfied' is at the moment)

I have not been able to accommplish this using this method

```
:disabled="!doesAllEventTypesHaveEventAttached"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return `null` when the condition is not satisfied, an attribute bound to `null` will not be rendered :

```html
<div :class="{someCondition? 'my-class':null" >
</div>
```

if the condition is false the rendered element will be

```html
<div >
</div>
```

Comment: This worked
`:data-popover-target="!doesAllEventTypesHaveEventAttached ? 'all-event-type-not-satisfied' : null "`

Thanks